# removing dictionary entries with no values- Python

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary, and I want to remove the entries in which the value is an empty list `[]` how would I go about doing that?

I tried:

```
for x in dict2.keys():
    if dict2[x] == []:
        dict2.keys().remove(x)
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.keys()` provides access to the list of keys in the dictionary, but changes to it are not (necessarily) reflected in the dictionary. You need to use `del dictionary[key]` or `dictionary.pop(key)` to remove it.

Because of the behaviour in some version of Python, you need to create a of copy of the list of your keys for things to work right. So your code would work if written as:

```
for x in list(dict2.keys()):
    if dict2[x] == []:
        del dict2[x]
```

Comment: Does not work, because you cannot change the size of a dictionary during iteration.

Comment: Corrected for Python 2.5/2.6/2.7/3.1.

Comment: In Python 3 it behaves differently, and gets angry if you modify the dict while iterating over `.keys()`. (Python 2 automatically creates a list, I believe.)

Answer (score 14):

Newer versions of python support dict comprehensions:

```
dic = {i:j for i,j in dic.items() if j != []}
```

These are much more readable than filter or for loops

Answer (score 3):

```
for x in dict2.keys():
    if dict2[x] == []:
        del dict2[x]
```

Comment: Using .keys() creates a new list to iterate, allowing you to delete from the original.

Good Work

Comment: It does not do so in Python 3, and this will raise `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just keep those which are not empty and let the gc to delete leftovers?  I mean:

```
dict2 = dict( [ (k,v) for (k,v) in dict2.items() if v] )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in [ k for (k,v) in dict2.items() if not v ]:
  del dict2[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean one, but it will create copy of that dict:

```
dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] != [], d.iteritems()))
```

Answer (score 1):

With generator object instead of list:

```
a = {'1': [], 'f':[1,2,3]}
dict((data for data in a.iteritems() if data[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def dict_without_empty_values(d):
    return {k:v for k,v in d.iteritems() if v}


# Ex;
dict1 = {
    'Q': 1,
    'P': 0,
    'S': None,
    'R': 0,
    'T': '',
    'W': [],
    'V': {},
    'Y': None,
    'X': None,
}

print dict1
# {'Q': 1, 'P': 0, 'S': None, 'R': 0, 'T': '', 'W': [], 'V': {}, 'Y': None, 'X': None}

print dict_without_empty_values(dict1)
# {'Q': 1}
```

Comment: how can we do this is in python2.6?